# What are the acceptable patterns for instance referencing on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, dom

I'm looking for patterns which have been found acceptable when working with instances of js objects on the same page. *(If there is a thread already covering this, a link will be appreciated.)*

The issue is one of reference. After an object/feature is instantiated, it has to be referenced at some point later.

I've seen jQuery people store a reference to the object *on* the target DOM element using `data()`. However, I'm interested in a framework agnostic option if possible.

This could be accomplished if there was a clean, viable way to generate an unique id for a DOM element. Alas, I have not found one yet.

So my question is: What is the best way to store reference to an object, via a DOM element, so that you can reference it at a future arbitrary time?

Hopefully this makes sense, and I'm not just rambling. :)

Thanks.

Comment: In HTML5, custom attributes starting with `data-` are allowed on elements. You could set the attribute to some ID and use that ID later to reference to a specific object instance.

Comment: @pimvdb Sure, that would work. However if there is any way to do it without actually modifying the DOM itself, it would be preferable. It might not be possible though. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Well, in that case you could set up an object which would act as a dictionary between an element's ID and references to objects. Just an idea, please ignore it if it's nonsense.

Comment: @primvdb It makes great sense. However it would require that the target DOM element have an id set. Not sure that is something I want to require for using this code. And please, don't be sorry. Any constructive answer is helpful. :)

Comment: I think I can't help you further I'm afraid. I guess you'll either have to be able to identify the element or change the element itself. Otherwise there is no ability to know which element you're assigning data to, but I might be mistaking.

Comment: @spot: Why is it preferable not to modify the DOM? Seems like a very reasonable way to do it, which is why most libraries do it, jQuery being just one that works exactly this way. Don't think of it as DOM pollution but DOM enhancement ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from maintaining your own cache:

```
var cache = [];

function locate(el) {
    // search for the element within our cache.
    for (var i=0;i<cache.length;i++) {
        if (cache[i].elem === el) {
            return cache[i].data;
        };
    };

    // if we get this far, it isn't in the cache: add it and return it.
    return cache[cache.push({
        elem: el,
        data: {}
    }) - 1].data;
};

// used to add data to an element and store it in our cache.
function storeData(el, data) {
    var store = locate(el);

    for (var x in data) {
        store[x] = data[x];
    };
};

// used to retrieve all data stored about the target element.
function getData(el) {
    return locate(el);
};
```

and then use as follows:

```
storeData(document.getElementById("foo"), {
    something: 4,
    else: "bar"
});

var data = getData(document.getElementById("foo"));
alert(data.something); // "4";
```

Comment: Ok, yeah. So this is exactly like using jQuery's data() framework, but building it out yourself. I currently have an implementation much like this working. Yet, the looping through the cache stack, just to see if an element exists feels so dirty. :) If it's the only way though, then it is what it is. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in JavaScript (unlike classical OOP languages) can be augmented. There's nothing wrong with that; that's the way JavaScript was designed to be used:

Write:

document.getElementById( 'foo' ).customAttribute = 5;

Read:

alert( document.getElementById( 'foo' ).customAttribute );

If you don't want to alter the original object, the only way to point at it is using a dictionary as pointed out in one of the previous answers; however, you don't need to do a linear search to find the object: it can be done in logarithmic time providing you use an ID per element (potentially not its HTML ID but a custom one)

Comment: DOM interactions are expensive, the dictionary works just fine. Thanks.